# LinQ join (having error in (on equals a to b))

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I have two tables, and second table have a foreign key pointing to table first.

First Table (model in .net)

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string AdRefId { get; set; }
    }
```

Second Table

```
public class UserTeamRoleMapping
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Team? TeamId { get; set; }

        
        [Required]
        public User? UserId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public Roles? RoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Problem is its showing error while joining these two tables in LinQ

```
var res = from u in _dbC.User
                      join utr in _dbC.UserTeamRoleMapping on u.Id equals utr.UserId into g
                      from r in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where (r.TeamId != teamId)
                      select new
                      {
                          Uid = u.Id,
                          UName = ht[u.AdRefId]
                      };
```

shown error in image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrlBD.png)

Please tell me a way so that i can compare Guid type value with Foreign key value.

I have already tried "utr.UserId as System.Guid" in join, but it still giving error.

Please help fast, A huge thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the "User" type ? I guess it's a Guid. If so, what you want is to have "UserId" of type Guid in DB, and a navigation property "User" to resolve the User record associated to it. Or, if the type is correct, you probably need to do something like "UserId.Id" in your join.

Comment: What is `ht`? You can't use local variables like that in LinqToEF.

Comment: Don't join. Use navigation properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: @Aron ht is hastable, and its working in LinQ

Comment: That hash table WILL NOT work with Linq2EF.

Answer (score 0):

Change your UserTeamRoleMapping class file to this

```
public class UserTeam
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Team? TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("userId")]
    public User? UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Roles? RoleId { get; set; 
}
```

Here you have to mention a foreign key for the User with annotation after this i was not getting the error in the linq.